# ajax taking too much time to send data.But data returned is crazy fast

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is the jquery  part.

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:  "index.php",
    data: { w1: js.who, w2: $(this).parent().attr("id") },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        if(data)
        {
            $.each(data.a, function(){
                $("#chat").append("<li>"+this+"</li>");
            });
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
        console.log(xhr.statusText);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

i am trying  to  send a  jquery object along with  id to  the same  php file but  it  is taking too  long to  send  data.what  can  be  the  problems?it  had  never  happened  earlier..

Comment: who is taking more time ?  your ajax script or your php?

Comment: how are you determining the sending and receiving speeds

Comment: its  is  taking too  much  time  to  start a  ajax  request  after and  event!!

Comment: what is in js.who? And what is index.php doing? And did you try looking into the http streams with [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/)?

Comment: i  am  starting  ajax  after focus event  in  input

Comment: js is  the  object,who  is an  instance containing string "ashish"

Comment: the data is  returned  instantly after ajax  beforeSend starts .i e  i have two  function  alerting start and top in the beforeSend and complete  function,they happen  instantly,  but the problem is  its  taking too  much time  to send  the  data!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code looks clean and simple to me, so the problem must be in the things you did not post.

You say it is the sending (not receiving) part that takes long time, so it must be one of the following:

1. Is `js.who` containing references to some huge object? In this case it may take a long time to json encode it. Try removing it and see if it fixes it.
2. Are you sending it only once (it's not happening in a loop or anything?)
3. How did you test that "data is returned crazy fast"? Did you send another POST request by some other means, or simply passed a string to the browser? If the latter is the case, perhaps index.php is behaving differently on GET and on POST. Test it.
4. What is "this" referring to (in the line with `data:...`)? Make sure it is a dom element.